How to Document Custom Parameter Decorators in Swagger for NestJS?
We have created custom parameter decorators in our NestJS service and are using Swagger for API documentation. However, I am unable to get the custom parameter decorators to show up in the Swagger UI.
I referred to this GitHub issue and tried to apply the suggested solution, but I encountered an error and couldn't identify the cause. Here is an example of one of our custom parameter decorators:


export const OrderParams = createParamDecorator(
  <T extends string = 'id'>(
    data: unknown,
    ctx: ExecutionContext,
  ): Ordering<T> => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const sort = new Ordering<T>(request.query);

    return sort;
  },
);



and here is how we are trying to use it in our controller:


@Get('selection/:activitySelectionId/applicant')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard, ActivityGuard(ActivityGuardStrategy.SELECTION))
async getActivitySelectionApplicantsNew(
    @ActivitySelectionParam() activitySelection: ActivitySelection,
    @OptionalPaginationParams() paginate: Paginate | undefined, // TODO
    @OrderParams() ordering: Ordering, // TODO
    @Query('questionId') questionId: number | undefined,
    @Query('query') query: string | undefined,
)



Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you!
